# What happens when hash tables generate huge hashcodes?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

I'm a little confused about hashmaps/hashtables, because everywhere I look, I don't really get the answer im looking for. I still don't know if hashmaps use a static array or if they use dynamic lookup. This is how I thought hashmaps were stored at first:

```
[Bucket 0] Object 1
[Bucket 4] Object 2
[Bucket 8000] Object 3
```

I thought that if you wanted to get the value from bucket 8000 you would have to search through every bucket key before it until you reached 8000. Now after reading and watching some videos Im thinking its stored as a basic array like:

```
[Bucket 0] Object 1
[...3 buckets in between]
[Bucket 4] Object 2
[...7795 buckets in between]
[Bucket 8000] Object 2
```

But then when something generated huge hash codes it would waste tons of memory. Then somewhere learned that maybe it uses the `%` operator to keep them from using indexes too big, but then each bucket would be more likely to have a collision. So which is it? I would think the most sensible one would be idea number one but I'm not sure. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you're basing these assumptions on.  Looking at the HashMap source code is better than guessing.  Looks like there is a mapping between hash values and indexes that means you aren't wasting tons of memory.  Joshua Bloch is much smarter than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash code is taken modulo the array length to generate an in-bounds index (`HashMap` in particular first applies a secondary hash function to the given hash code to protect against poorly written hash functions). If the hash table begins to fill up past a certain threshold, the array is expanded and all of the elements are re-inserted. Collisions *are* possible, but with a good hash function they *should* be rare.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I don't like that answer but I guess it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @user3803380 No problem. What don't you like?

Comment: I guess the fact that it still uses memory for unused elements but Its probably not that big a deal.

Comment: @user3803380 Generally it's not. That's the trade-off for constant time querying/updating.